# C# AES encryption performs only once

Tags: c#, winforms, cryptography

I have a C# WinForms app, with AES encryption/decryption. The encryption (decryption) itself works fine, but only once. If I try to encrypt another string, I get a CryptographyException saying the padding is invalid. Based on some research, it seems I forgot to close some stream, but I can't figure out what it is. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Here is the code I use (I believe I found it earlier somewher on SO):

```
    static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key
, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an Aes object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key
, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt
, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(
csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                        //csDecrypt.FlushFinalBlock(); causes an exception
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                            //csDecrypt.Flush(); experimental solution, doesn't work           either
                            srDecrypt.Close();
                    }
                    csDecrypt.Close();

                }
                msDecrypt.Close();
            }        

        }

        return plaintext;

    }

    static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key,
byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        byte[] encrypted;
        // Create an Aes object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key
, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt
, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(
csEncrypt))
                    {

                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        swEncrypt.Close();
                    }
                    csEncrypt.Close();
                    msEncrypt.Close();
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();

                    //csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock(); causes an exception saying it was already called
                }

            }
        }
```

Here is a sample of code I use to test the ecnryption. Performs correctly, but only once...
The key and IV are converted into Unicode string so that the user is able to save it and use it later for decryption.

```
        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string aesKey = "";
        string aesIV = "";
        string ciphered = "";
        string deciphered = "";
        using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
        {
            myAes.GenerateKey();
            myAes.GenerateIV();
            aesKey = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(myAes.Key);
            aesIV = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(myAes.IV);

            ciphered = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(".ahoj.",    myAes.Key, myAes.IV));

            byte[] deKey = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(aesKey);
            byte[] deIv = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(aesIV);

            deciphered =    DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(ciphered), deKey, deIv);

            MessageBox.Show("key: " + aesKey + "\niv: " + aesIV + "\ndekey: " + Encoding.Unicode.GetString(deKey) + "\ndeIv: " + Encoding.Unicode.GetString(deIv) + "\nDeciphered: " + deciphered);

        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `GetBytes` and `GetString` from the unicode encoding, I would recommend base 64 encoding the bytes.

You can do base 64 encoding using `Convert.ToBase64String()` and `Convert.FromBase64String`.

One problem with just getting the unicode string from a generated byte array is that there is no guarantee that all of the characters are printable characters.  For example, if you have a 0 in the byte array, that will be a null control character.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this myself. I am making use of the 'using' statements in your first code block but I never call `.Close()` and I am not running into the issue of only being able to run once.

To solve issues with padding on decrypt and issue of non-printable characters, I am explicitly setting the `Padding` as you did in the first code block but I am using `Encoding.Default.GetBytes(cipherText);` and the `GetString` method of the same encoding so it uses Window's default Extended ASCII encoding so it will recognize all the characters.

Comment: While using extended ASCII encoding might work most of the time I am sure you are still going to hit edge cases where it will fail. using base64 encoding is the industry standard way of representing a set of bytes as a block of text.